# Links not working on enter keyword in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using autocompleter and getting result populated in li's like this

```
<ul> 
<a href="/sale123/604/" style="display:block">  
  <li class="suggestedItems">   
    <div class="floatLeft foundImages">
       <img width="45" height="45" src="primary.png"> 
    </div> 
    <div class="foundResult"> <span class="dIB primaryTitle font12">18th century wine bottle - testc </span> <span class="dIB font12 secondaryTitle">Product</span> 
    </div> 
  </li> 
</a> 
</ul>
```

My concern is when result is getting populated inside li's, there is two options provided by plugin either I can click on the results using enter keyword or I can click on it using mouse both the function is working fine in firefox but in google chrome the enter keyword is not working. On enter keyword nothing is happening. Any suggestion why its not working.

Comment: My simple question is why a href is not working on enter key ? Yes I am trying to create a jsfiddle

Comment: Oh, you mean, how to programmatically trigger a link?

Comment: Yes, Every thing is fine with all the browsers but only with google chrome when i try to click using enter keyword nothing is happening. Its not redirecting the page.

Comment: I just tried to move over li's through TAB and then i press enter now its working fine :( So Its working through tab which i didnt want. I think its not getting focus on simple enter press.